# Why private-inheritance object allows member function cast derived* to base* but outsiders not?

Tags: c++

I am checking a [FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance) about private-inheritance, I am not well understand the following two conclusions, could somebody give some explain?

**In neither case can users (outsiders) convert a Car* to an Engine* ?**

**The private-inheritance variant allows members of Car to convert a Car* to an Engine*?**

> private inheritance is a syntactic variant of composition (AKA
>   aggregation and/or has-a).
>
> E.g., the “Car has-a Engine” relationship can be expressed using
>   simple composition:
>
> ```
> class Engine {
> public:
>   Engine(int numCylinders);
>   void start();                 // Starts this Engine
> };
> class Car {
> public:
>   Car() : e_(8) { }             // Initializes this Car with 8 cylinders
>   void start() { e_.start(); }  // Start this Car by starting its Engine
> private:
>   Engine e_;                    // Car has-a Engine
> };
> ```
>
> The “Car has-a Engine” relationship can also be expressed using
>   private inheritance:
>
> ```
> class Car : private Engine {    // Car has-a Engine
> public:
>   Car() : Engine(8) { }         // Initializes this Car with 8 cylinders
>   using Engine::start;          // Start this Car by starting its Engine
> };
> ```
>
> How are “private inheritance” and “composition” similar? There are
>   several similarities between these two variants:
>
> - In both cases there is exactly one Engine member object contained in every Car object
> - In neither case can users (outsiders) convert a Car* to an Engine*
> - In both cases the Car class has a start() method that calls the start() method on the contained Engine object.
>
> There are also several distinctions:
>
> - The simple-composition variant is needed if you want to contain
>     several Engines per Car
> - The private-inheritance variant can introduce unnecessary multiple inheritance
> - The private-inheritance variant allows members of Car to convert a Car* to an Engine*
> - The private-inheritance variant allows access to the protected members of the base class
> - The private-inheritance variant allows Car to override Engine’s virtual functions
> - The private-inheritance variant makes it slightly simpler (20 characters compared to 28 characters) to give Car a start() method that simply calls through to the Engine’s start() method

Comment: There is another distinction that is missed: private inheritance will force the usage of vtables.

Comment: @van dench that is not necessary true, base class might not have virtual function.

Comment: I’m pretty sure constructors still force vtables.

Comment: @vandench constructors do not force vtables, only virtual methods (or virtual inheritance) do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The motivation behind the `private` keyword in C++ is [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) -- by hiding details about your class, the compiler can make sure that other code (outside your class's own code) cannot and therefore does not rely on those details, and therefore the compiler helps you guarantee that the other code won't need to be modified if/when you change those details in the future.

In this case, if you are deriving your subclass via private inheritance, you are telling the compiler that outside code should not be allowed to know about that inheritance.  As far as the outside code is concerned, the relation between your `Car` class and the `Engine` class does not exist (except as an implementation detail that they don't get to know about).  Code that is part of your `Car` class, on the other hand, is "insider" code, so it gets to know about that relationship and take advantage of it, if it wants to do so.  That way if you ever change the relationship (e.g. if you change `Car` to subclass from `Vehicle` rather than `Engine`), you might have to rewrite some of the code inside your `Car` class, but you won't have to go out and fix any other code elsewhere that was relying on the fact that `Car` subclasses `Engine`, because outside code was never allowed to rely on that relationship in the first place.